# How can I show what the user types in the text field while I display its result on the same page in PHP?

Tags: php, textfield, display

My instructor told us to make a PHP script that will count the vowels of whatever the user input in the textarea. At the same time show the result below it. And I already did it.

But then the instructor told us that she also wants to see at the same time after showing the result **what the user input in the textarea**.. I'm still searching how to do that.. Can someone help me with it?

I use PHP_SELF and method POST in `<form>` tag to show the results.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$text = $_POST['sentence'];

if ($_POST['display']){
    $message1 = "The sentence is \"$text\".";
    $message2 = "There are ".countVowels($text)." vowels in the sentence.";
}
 function isVowel($ch){
     $flag = false;
     $vowels = "aeiou";
     for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($vowels); $i++)
        if ($ch == $vowels[$i])
            $flag = true;
    return $flag;
 }
 function countVowels($str){
     $counter = 0;
     for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
        if (isVowel($str[$i]) == true)
            $counter++;
    return $counter;
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Count the vowels</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">
            <p>Enter a sentence: </p>
            <textarea name ="sentence" cols = "75" rows = "20" placeholder = "Type here..." ></textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type = "submit" name = "display" value = "Count Vowels"/>
            <?php
                echo $message1;
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $message2;
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output after clicking the count vowels button:
The textarea should have user input text in it.

and will display the:

The sentence is $sentence.
There are $countVowels($sentence) vowels in the sentence.

Comment: Can't you just echo $text?

Comment: Doesn't `The sentence is \"$text\".` show what they inputted? Some other notes that might not be needed, this is open to XSS injections. `y` sometimes is a vowel e.g. `fly`.

Comment: echo $_POST['sentence'];

Comment: If you mean at the same time the user is typing, that would need to be done with javascript/jquery. Either duplicate the functions and watch the textfield (fast), or post the data via ajax to the PHP script (slow).

Comment: `countVowels` also won't account for capital vowels. Might want to add `if (strtolower($ch)` or you could use `preg_replace` and the 5th count parameter.

Comment: Why did you remove your code? What happened when you executed that code? It should have given the count an the original input.

Comment: @aynber what do you mean by what you said about the double the functions and the like. for now, i didnt study the javascript.

Comment: @user3783243 thank you. i almost forgot about the uppercase.

Comment: @ChadK i can do that ... but my instructor showed us that that should be the output.

Comment: By duplicate, I mean write a similar function in javascript/jquery. You can use an onChange event to update the calculations as they type.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do simply?

```
<?php
     echo $message1;
     echo "<br/>";
     echo $message2;
     echo "<br/>";
     isset($_POST['display']) ? echo $_POST['sentence] : '';
?>
```